# case statement error while using difference of columns with time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, teradata

I would like to write a single select query with a case statement. Requirement is to get the time difference between col1 and col2 in seconds and case statement is like, if the difference is < 60 sec, then low, if diff > 60 then high end as range.

What i tried so far is:

```
select id, ((col1-col2)*24*60)*60 as diff_secs from table;
```

This is giving me the difference in seconds, which is perfect. But in order to incorporate the case statement, i tried the below but not working.

```
select id, case when (((col1-col2)*24*60)*60) < 60 then low
                when (((col1-col2)*24*60)*60) > 60 then high
                then end as range
from tble;
```

Comment: `then end` --> `end`.

Comment: That's a case _expression_, it returns a value. (A case _statement_ is used in stored proceduresto do conditional execution of code.)

Comment: What's the data type of col1 and col2?

Comment: both of them are date time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an inline view it can be achieved:

```
 select id,case when diff_secs < 60 then 'low' 
                when diff_secs > 60 then 'high'
           end as Range 
  from 
       (select id, ((col1-col2)*24*60)*60 as diff_secs 
        from table) 
  diff_secs_data
```

PS: The query doesn't handle equal to 60, you might have to modify based on your requirement.

EDIT: To find count of 'high' and 'low' records,aggregation with an additional inline view should suffice.
There could be multiple ways, but i prefer using inline view as that gives better readability.

```
select Range,count(*)
 from 
 (select id,case when diff_secs < 60 then 'low' 
                when diff_secs > 60 then 'high'
           end as Range 
  from 
       (select id, ((col1-col2)*24*60)*60 as diff_secs 
        from table) 
  diff_secs_data) range_data
  group by Range;
```

Comment: If i want to get the count in my query, how can i get it? I mean i just want to see the count for 'low', count for 'high', etc...

Comment: You need *conditional aggregation*: `select id,count(case when diff_secs < 60 then 1 end) as low,
count(case when diff_secs > 60 then 1 end) as high 
  from ... group by id`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the small typo I would say you can rephrase it as:

```
select 
  id, 
  case when col1 < col2 + interval '1' minute then 'low'
       else 'high' 
  end as range
from tble;
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=64a21d80afc61487e6f7fef061590c70).

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should work, but I would recommend:

```
(case when col1 < col2 + interval '1' minute then 'low'
      when col1 > col2 + interval '1' minute then 'high'
 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed using Teradata (you also tagged Oracle), you can simplify it a bit using an alias:

```sql
SELECT id, (((col1-col2)*24*60)*60) AS time_diff,
  CASE 
    WHEN time_diff < 60 THEN 'low'
    WHEN time_diff > 60 THEN 'high'
  END AS range
from tble;
```

You may also want to account for the case where the time difference is exactly 60 by adding an "=" to one of the operands in the case expression.

Comment: This is not working in Oracle with the error *missing keyword*

Comment: Right, this will only work on Teradata, not Oracle.  You indicated Oracle and Teradata in your original post.